# I had just missed your call

Tags: meaning, adverbs, ambiguity

When John walked in, I had just missed your call.,

Does that mean

1. When John walked in, I had missed your call by a very narrow margin. I almost managed to get it.

or

2. I had missed your call a moment ago.

?

I think it could mean both but I'd interpret it as (2) unless context made me think otherwise.

Many thanks

Comment: It's an odd thing to say, so I don't think either interpretation is the usual one, since this isn't something that I would normally say.

Comment: "When John walked in, I had just got home." would be fine. But since missing a call isn't something you do as much as something that happens, it's a bit weird to say "I had just missed your call" rather than "you had just tried to call". Unless you mean that you had deliberately ignored the call?

Comment: The past prefect is used to say something that precedes another past event so 2) does not work. The "had missed your call" precedes the missed your call.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately 2) has no time frame reference. Do you mean from the time John walked in or from the time the sentence is spoken?
In any case, unless there is some other context, native English speakers would interpret it as meaning 1). The following time sequence would be assumed.

1. You phoned
2. I heard it ringing, but
3. I failed to failed to reach the phone before the call timed out.
4. John walked in soon afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

John's walking in does not *entail* a particular understanding of "had *just* missed", which could mean "had missed only a moment earlier" or "had picked up right as you had ended the call". Without additional context, it's not really possible to decide between those options. What does John walking in have to do with either possibility, really? You would have to summon up a context out of thin air in either case, and the question would come down to what is the more likely or more plausible of those contexts.

> When John walked in, I had just missed your call. That's why I was hanging my coat on the coat rack when John walked in. You had called before I arrived at the office.
>
> When John walked in, I had just missed your call.  That's why I was huffing and puffing when he walked in. I had heard my phone ringing from the conference room at the far end of the hall. I ran down the hall but didn't quite get to it in time.

Comment: Thank you all so much. 2 should have been 'I had missed your call a moment before John waled in'. I think 'just' could be interpreted in two ways. as Tim points out.  You have the 'only a moment earlier' possibility and 'the almost didn't miss' possibility.  That was the idea. Thanks again to all. A special thanks to Tim, and my apologies for not having been clear.